# Hosting backend files onto IIS

Tags: reactjs, iis, backend, hosting

I'm trying to upload my website onto the web. I have two folders for holding my front-end React files and another for the back-end files that uses Nodejs, cors, and express. It also has my API and middleware.

The front-end pages have already been uploaded onto my IIS and port forwarded with my router, so I can access that anywhere with my IP. But it doesn't function well without my backend files, how can I host the backend files as well and make them work together?

I am getting a headache doing this, does anyone know how to do this??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you want to host node.js application, you should firstly install the node.exe and the a build of iisnode.

[node.exe](https://nodejs.org/en/#download)

[iisnode](https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode)

After installed the IIS nodes, you could set up samples, from the administrative command prompt call %programfiles%\iisnode\setupsamples.bat.

Then you could go to http://localhost/node to see the example.

The next step is to deploy the node.js application inside one iis web application.

Lastly, you should create or modify the web.config to use the iisnode modules.
For example,

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>

    <handlers>
        <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
    </handlers>

    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="mysite">
                <match url="/*" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="app.js" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>

</system.webServer>
```

More details, you could refer to below article:

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingAndRunningNodejsApplicationsWithinIISOnWindowsAreYouMad.aspx